# Deploying a Google App Engine app written in Java from Travis CI fails

Tags: java, google-app-engine, deployment, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm playing around with Google App Engine with a Java application.  I'm using Travis' [GAE `deploy` provider](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/google-app-engine) to attempt to deploy my simple app.  However, despite following the steps and providing the correct information, I get this error at the deployment step:

```
ERROR: File [src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml] is not a valid deployable yaml file.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Errors occurred while parsing the App Engine app configuration.
```

The first part in particular confuses me; why is GAE asking me for a YAML file when you're supposed to configure Java GAE apps with `appengine-web.xml`?

This is the `.travis.yml` for the project:

```
language: java
sudo: false
jdk:
  - openjdk7
  - oraclejdk7

before_deploy:
  - mvn appengine:update

deploy:
  provider: gae
  keyfile: gae-secret.json
  project: jtalaveragre-tic-tac-toe
  config: src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
  on:
    jdk: oraclejdk7
cache:
  directories:
  - $HOME/.m2

before_install:
- openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_662077106e81_key -iv $encrypted_662077106e81_iv
  -in gae-secret.json.enc -out gae-secret.json -d
```